# OpenSCAD | Scale text to a specific width but without exceeding a specific max-height

Tags: openscad

Is it possible to scale text in OpenSCAD to a specific width, but without exceeding a max-height?

Answer (score 0):

use `resize()`, see [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#resize),
for example:

```
width = 20;
resize([100, width, 1]) text("arbitrary text");
```